# Using jquery getscript to load Sharepoint 2013 resource - testing resources are already loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, peoplepicker

I want to use jquery's getScript function to load some sharepoint 2013 script resource files.  Specifically those related to the 'people picker'

- autofill.js
- clientpeoplepicker.js
- clientforms.js

This action is to be performed each time the user clicks a custom 'add person' button.  Is there a way to test if these scripts are already loaded?

Comment: What does your custom 'add person' button do? Does it refresh the page? If it's going to only be used on that button you could just use getScript to load the scripts (have a nested getScript to load all three .js files) and then run your code after.

Comment: The add person will get the login name/id of the selected user, It will call the SP Rest API to add that person to a selected user group.  The custom code is in a SP PageViewer webpart - an iframe.  I've made progress on this.  getScript is loading these files but there are all sorts of other dependencies missing (ex. clienttemplates.js , ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded and Array.addRange).  Is there a listing of all required dependencies?